# Alignment/Packing in Python Struct.Unpack

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I have a piece of hardware sending data at a fixed length: 2bytes, 1 bytes, 4 bytes, 4 bytes, 2 bytes, 4bytes for a total of 17 bytes.  If I change my format to 18bytes the code works but values are incorrect.

```
format = '<2s1s4s4s2s4s'
print(struct.calcsize(format))
print(len(hardware_data))
splitdata = struct.unpack(format,hardware_data)
```

The output is 17, 18 and an error because of the mismatch.  I think this is caused by alignment but I'm unsure and nothing I've tried had fixed this. Below are a couple typical strings, if I `print(hardware_data)`   I noticed the 'R' and 'n' characters but I'm unsure how to handle.

b'\x18\x06\x00R\x1f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd8\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80'

b'\x18\x06\x00R\x1f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are whatever is sending the data is padding it in some way you're not expecting.

For example, if the first four byte field is supposed to represent an `int`, C struct padding rules would require a padding byte, after the one byte field (to align the next four byte field to four byte alignment). So just add the padding byte explicitly, changing your format string to:

```
format = '<2s1sx4s4s2s4s'
```

The `x` in there says "I expect a byte here, but it's padding, don't unpack it to anything." It's possible the pad byte belongs elsewhere (I have no idea what your hardware is doing); I notice the third byte is the NUL (`\0`) byte in both examples, but the spot I assumed would be padding is `'R'`, so it's possible you want:

```
format = '<2sx1s4s4s2s4s'
```

instead. Or it could be somewhere else (without knowing which of the fields is a `char` array in the hardware struct, and which are larger types with alignment requirements, it's impossible to say). Point is, your hardware is sending 18 bytes; figure out which one is garbage, and put the `x` pad byte at the appropriate location.

Side-note: The `repr` of `bytes` objects will use ASCII or simpler ASCII escapes when available. That's why you see an `R` and a `\n` in your output; `b'R'` and `b'\x52'` are equivalent literals, as are `b'\n'` and `b'\x0a'` and Python chooses to use the "more readable" version (when the `bytes` is actually just ASCII, this is *much* more readable).

Comment: Thanks!  I saw pad byte in the documentation but given it didn't show a size, I didn't understand what this did.  It's very obvious in hindsight.